# Adding Setting To Charm Windows 8 app

Tags: javascript, windows-8, windows-store-apps, privacy, windows-store

My Windows Store App certification failed and the note given to me by the tester is that:

> The app has declared access to network capabilities and no privacy statement was provided in the Windows Settings Charm.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to solve this problem?

I would appreciate if any solutions were Javascript based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The samples that MS provide suck but I have made a simple solution at http://eion.robbmob.com/blog/2013/04/02/win8-js-privacy-policy-settings/

Edit:
Attaching code here :)

```
var settingsPane = Windows.UI.ApplicationSettings.SettingsPane.getForCurrentView();
function commandsRequested(eventArgs) {
    var applicationCommands = eventArgs.request.applicationCommands;
    var privacyCommand = new Windows.UI.ApplicationSettings.SettingsCommand('privacy', 'Privacy Policy', function() {
        window.open('www.link.to.your/privacy_policy.html');
    });
    applicationCommands.append(privacyCommand);
}
settingsPane.addEventListener("commandsrequested", commandsRequested);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a Privacy Statement via a link in the Settings Charm for you application.  See Guidelines for App Settings - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh770544.aspx and the App Settings Sample - http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/App-settings-sample-1f762f49.

Look at existing Windows Store apps that you have installed for examples of Privacy Statements.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an [article documenting the privacy certification failure](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jennifer/archive/2012/11/15/common-windows-store-certification-errors-4-1-your-app-must-comply-with-privacy-requirements.aspx).  In short, uncheck the Internet (Client) capability in your app manifest if you aren't using the network, and if you are, the article tells what you need in a privacy policy, where to surface the privacy policy, and links to sample code.